# Linux: using grep to find a word in a file then printing if it does or does not have that word in the file

Tags: linux, string, bash, grep, find

I am trying to use the grep command however i do not know how to continue after the "grep $word $file" or even if that will work. What i need to do is get the program so that after they have typed in a word and a file if the word is in the file the program echo's "The word you have entered is in the file you have entered." and i also need it to print "I am sorry but the word you have entered is not in the file you have entered" if you can help it would be really helpful thank you

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome what please type in what you would like to do!"
echo "You can:"
echo "Search for words in file type (S)"
echo "Quit (Q)"
read option
while $option in
    do
            S)      echo "What is the name of the file you would like to search for?"
                    read file
                    echo "What word would you like to find in the file?"
                    read word
                    grep $word $file


            Q)      echo "Goodbye!"
                    exit
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grep -q` option to disable printing of the matching words and use `echo $?` to get the return value of grep. `0` is the return value if match found else `1` will be returned.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome what please type in what you would like to do!"
echo "You can:"
echo "Search for words in file type (S)"
echo "Quit (Q)"
read option
case $option in
            S)      echo "What is the name of the file you would like to search for?"
                    read file
                    echo "What word would you like to find in the file?"
                    read word
                    grep -q $word $file
                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                      echo "$word found in $file"
                    else
                      echo "$word NOT found in $file"
                    fi
                    ;;


            Q)      echo "Goodbye!"
                    exit
esac
```

Also you can use `grep -w` in case you want to match whole word. So your `grep` will look like

```
                grep -wq $word $file
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                  echo "$word found in $file"
                else
                  echo "$word NOT found in $file"
```

Comment: i am getting a error in line 9 would you be able to help me?

Comment: this is the error                                                ./fin2: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./fin2: line 9: `            S)      echo "What is the name of the file you would like to search for?"'

Comment: Can you specify the error and the line which throws error?

Comment: ./fin2: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./fin2: line 9: `            S)      echo "What is the name of the file you would like to search for?"'

Comment: ./fin2: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./fin2: line 8: `    do'

Comment: Check this link (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-case-statement/) for syntax of switch-case in bash

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner using `&&` and `||`

```
grep -q $word $file && echo "found the word" || echo "not found the word"
```

eg

```
$ echo hello | grep -q hell && echo "found the word" || echo "not found the word"
found the word

$ echo hello | grep -q help && echo "found the word" || echo "not found the word"
not found the word
```